# Error while merging multiple csv with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

**Requirement:** I have 69 csvs. Merge them on the basis of below condition:

**Condition:** If value in cell at header 'col7' = 1, append the corresponding row in new csv.

Can you please help me complete this piece of code?

Below is my code:

```
with open('merged.csv', 'a') as mergedFile:
    for csv in glob('*.csv'):
        if csv == 'merged.csv':
            pass
        else:
            for line in os.listdir():
                for eachFile in open(csv, 'r'):
                    # write further code here if header 'col7' value = 1
                        # write further code here to add the corresponding rows meeting condition
                        mergedFile.write(line)
```

If there is any way of doing this by **pandas**, most welcome.

Comment: the name of the csv file is merged? what is the unique feature in the names of the csv? Also, do u know the names of ur headers? if u do, the dict form in the csv module might be helpful

Comment: The new file to which I am wriiting to is "merged.csv". Unique feature is of no concern here, this is more of like filtering data. And header name which I want to put filter over is 'col7'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `csv` module is good for this task. You are mostly just filtering row by row. `pandas` would have to bring the whole csv into memory before writing.

```
import csv

# todo: do you want append, or use 'w' to start a new file?
with open('merged.csv', 'a', newline='') as mergedFile:
    writer = csv.writer(mergedFile)
    for csvFile in glob('*.csv'): # renamed variable to avoid module name collision
        if csvFile == 'merged.csv':
            continue
        with open(csvFile, newline='') as inFile:
            reader = csv.reader(inFile)
            # assuming there is a header with column names, we are looking for "col7"
            header = next(reader)
            try:
                filterCol = header.index("col7")
            except ValueError as e:
                print("no 'col7' in {}, skipping".format(csvFile))
                continue
            writer.writerows(row for row in reader if row[filterCol == "1")
```